# How to read functions from a string using regex from commands in Java or What are the alternative options?

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I want to give commands using function like structure in string. For example I have three functions:

```
go() do() hello()
```

but also these function have bodies that also could contain the same functions.

```
"go(){do(){go}} do()"
```

These functions can also use parameters.
How can I do this in regex. It is like creating a programming language.

Basically those are not methods but classes that are all implemented from the same abstract class. Each classes have a parameter by the type of list of those of the same classes. My intentions is like a calculator that accept parentheses.
5* (2+5-(5*9))

My commands can get complicated:

```
go(true, 4){do(), hello(){go(){}}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with several different languages, if you want a regex? — However, I don't think this is possible with a regex, as standard regexes can't support arbitrary nesting. I'd suggest looking at a simple parser, which is more complex but much more flexible.

Comment: Because any examples in those languages would be fine.

Comment: Have a look at BeanShell - scripted Java

Comment: Do you only want to parse the string or also do some kind of execution? What are the semantics of the curly brackets? In programming languages like java this would be used to declare commands or functions. In your example you pass literal values. So it is still not obvious what you are going to achieve. Can you explain?

Comment: Just parsing. I'm basically removing buttons and replacing it with a textbox to tell my app what to do. I'm trying to do this by special syntax created by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to parse recursive languages with undefined recursion depth you can't use regex that only parses regular languages and is implemented using a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

Use a parser generator like [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) instead that suppurts non-regular grammars. It includes grammar files for all kinds of existing programming languages that you can use as example for parsing your own language.

**Update:**

If this seems too oversized or too much to learn for what you want to do, you could call regex substitution in a loop and resolve the nested structure from inside to outside. Pseudo code:

```
while true:
  search any innermost bracket pair (that doesn't contain nested brackets) with regex
  if found:
    parse content of innermost bracket pair
    remove bracket and its content from input or substitute with something w/o brackets
  else:
    parse content of remaining input
    exit loop
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to make or find a simple example for ANTLR. It is interesting.

Comment: At the end of the [ANTLR getting started page](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) is a very basic example.

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding, We are having function calls as a string inside the function. If Yes, we can give a try to this `RegEx`.

```
\w+\([^\)]*\)
```

`\w` **:** matches word characters. i.e. `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, including `_ (underscore)`.

`+` **:** matches one or more occurrences of the word characters.

`\(` **:** matches opening round bracket

`[^\)]*` **:** matches zero or more characters except `/` and `)`

`\)` **:** matches closing round bracket

Live Demo (Just for a demo purpose I am using JavaScript, You can make the changes as per the Java) **:**

```js
const str = "go(){do(){go}} do()";

console.log(str.match(/\w+\([^\)]*\)/g));
// ["go()", "do()", "do()"]
```